# CSS - Using mix-blend-mode in Chrome over video, blend applied to element above

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a block of HTML for showing an image/video with a pattern and text on top of it:

```
<div id="video_block">
    <img src="montage_still.jpg" class="spacer_image">
    <img src="montage_still.jpg" class="background_image">
    <video width="100%;" height="auto;" muted="" preload="" autoplay="">
        Sources
    </video>
    <div class="overlay_pattern yellow"></div>
    <div class="overlay_text center_middle_text">Pride</div>
</div>
```

More simply, the layers are:

- Spacer Image *(to define space, not visible)*
- Image
- Video
- Overlay Pattern *(yellow blocks set to the background)*
- Overlay Text *(white text placed above everything else)*

What I am aiming for is the following, which occurs in most browsers over both the image and the video (when loaded/visible):

[image: Overlay elements working as expected.]

However, when using Chrome (Mac, 45.0.2454.85, 64-bit) and only when the video is visible, I get the following:

[image: Blend of pattern overlay is also applied up to the overlay text.]

This seems odd, given that when I read, "[the mix-blend-mode property defines how an element’s content should blend with its background](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/)," I assume that the pattern overlay would blend down with the image/video, leaving the text above it alone.  However, it appears that Chrome is giving the text overlay div the same blend effect; both elements change in unison when I change the blend mode to anything else.

The CSS:

```
img.background_image,
div.video_block video {
    position:absolute;
    //more styles
}

div.overlay_pattern {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    height: 200vh;
    left: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.overlay_pattern.yellow {
    background: url("yellow_pattern.png") repeat scroll;
}

div.overlay_text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Gotham A","Gotham B";
    font-size: 8em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.center_middle_text {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 10%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 80%;
}
```

Any advice to get consistent behavior for Chrome? (Is this is a bug, perhaps?)

Comment: The `mix-blend-mode: overlay` appears to only be working properly in Google Chrome (out of the browsers you have tested).  That's how the overlay value _should_ look.  Check this out: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/GxlBm  Try changing the `mix-blend-mode` to `overlay`, then change it to `normal`.  I believe that `normal` is what you are looking for, though that is the default value so you could likely just do without it entirely.

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard I'm not trying to apply the `mix-blend-mode` to the text (as seen above) and rather just the overlay div below it with the yellow squares.  The issue is that, for some inexplicable reason the `mix-blend-mode` is also applied up to the text.  I altered your Pen to try and replicate the issue...and I don't see the same behavior as in the text site...arg. http://codepen.io/mischlern/pen/BojPdB